# Facebook Warning for entering the credentials is not coming on real device IOS6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6, social-framework

When we test IOS6 Facebook sharing feature in real device its not showing the Alert view with Setting and cancel button but working fine in the IOS6 simulator. We tested in iphone 4s and Iphone5 , In both phones its not showing and alert view for entering the credentials in settings page .

Did any one found the same isssue ?

Comment: Did these devices already have Facebook accounts configured?

Comment: I'm having the SAME EXACT problem!!! When the Fb Account is not set up in device Settings on the simulator, the 'Add Fb Account' dialog automatically shows. But on an actual device (iPhone 5 for example) the dialog does not pop up to prompt the user to add their Facebook account.

Answer (score 0):

With the new Social.Framework, If the user does not setup his account for Facebook, Twitter or Weebo in Settings , The App will not recognize that you have Facebook available.

Go to settings and then to the Twitter or Facebook tabs where you can setup your account credentials. After this is setup it will work correctly.

This works fine in the simulator but not on a phone if the relevant accounts are not setup.

[image]
[image]
[image]